# How do you automatically refresh part of a page automatically using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
$messages = $db->query("SELECT * FROM chatmessages ORDER BY datetime DESC, displayorderid DESC LIMIT 0,10");
while($message = $db->fetch_array($messages)) {
    $oldmessages[] = $message['message'];
}
$oldmessages = array_reverse($oldmessages);
?>
<div id="chat">
<?php
for ($count = 0; $count < 9; $count++) {
    echo $oldmessages[$count];
}
?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
setInterval( "document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML='<NEW CONTENT OF #CHAT>'", 1000 );
-->
</script>
</div>
```

I'm trying to create a PHP chatroom script but I'm having a lot of trouble getting it to AutoRefresh

The content should automatically update to , how do you make it do that? I've been searching for almost an hour

Comment: Just for the record AJAX *is* JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

I would take that PHP functionality you have and putting it in a sperate page that returns JSON. From there you can call that method using jQuery and the AJAX tools built in. Really simple. Start here for jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: As much as I love JSON to work with, I've found a lot of hosts and servers don't have it enabled on PHP by default (Espec as the JSON_FORCE_OBJECT constant was not added until 5.3, and not everyone has upgraded yet), and don't like enabling it, so I think that XML would probably be a better way to go, until it becomes more widely supported.

Comment: Then use SOAP over JSON, either way you will want to use some sort of async method to retrieve that data.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to set up a server side script that renders only the contents of the chat div and use ajax to grab that. it can be done with jquery quite easily:

In your html document:

```
<head>
...
    <script src="/path/to/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        var chatUpdateInterval = null;
        function initChat() {
            chatUpdateInterval = window.setInterval(updateChat, 5000); /* every 5 seconds */
        }
        function updateChat() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/url/path/to/your/script.php'
               ,dataType: 'HTML'
               ,success: function(data, status, xhr){
                   $('#chat').append($(data).html());
               }
            });
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
             initChat();
        });
    </script>
...
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chat">
      please stand by while we're firing up the coal!
    </div>
</body>
```

Note that this won't be really good, it's just a sample to get you started. you should look into jquery's [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)